# Wrap substrings in React components

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a `FragmentedString` class, which is a string with one or multiple distinct substrings.

```js
class FragmentedString {
    str: string;
    fragments: Array<{
        id: string;
        start: number;
        end: number;
    }>
}
```

All the verification needed to ensure this fragmented string is valid has been done previously. Let's say we have the following `FragmentedString`, and every word "substring" is a substring.

```
This is a beautiful string with a few substrings, such as this substring and this other substring.
```

```
This is a beautiful string with a few [substring]s, such as this [substring] and this other [substring].
```

If I had to wrap every substring in an `<a>` tag, I would insert them and set `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` on a div. But what if I wanted to wrap these in React components? How can I do that? I thought of `eval`, which not only sounds like a bad idea, but I'm not sure if it supports either TypeScript or JSX. What's your take?

#### Edit

To avoid the XY problem: I would like the state of a parent component to be changed depending on the substring clicked. It would be something like that in React.

```js
class Component {
    handleEvent(e) {
        // use e.target.name to extract the substring id, and set the parent state using a method passed as a prop
    }
    render() {
       return (
           <p>String <a name="substring_id" onClick={this.handleEvent.bind(this)}>substring</a></p>
       )
    }
}
```

Note that even though I use `<a>` here with its `name` property for storing the id, it may not be the right decision, I let you judge.

Comment: Why not create a component that is capable of rendering a `FragmentedString` without any `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`?

Comment: Well, yes, the question is *how*. How do you insert React tags in a string?

Comment: You wouldn't do that in the first place. The component should instead split the string into several parts given the fragments and then create the correct markup from that parts wrapping the fragments in the desired tags.

Comment: HTML tags, then? I'd like a parent component's state to be changed when the substring is clicked. I don't really know how I could do that without React in a React app.

Comment: I didn't say without react but definitely without any `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` or even `eval`. Why can't you just pass the fragmented string as a prop to a component that splits it into parts and wraps the fragments with a tag. You could even provide the component that the fragments should be wrapped in in another prop.

Comment: I'm sorry, this sounds like a good idea, but I'm not sure I get how you'd do that. Would you mind showing it in an answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235620/discussion-between-a2br-and-trixn).

Comment: Here's a recent answer of mine for a similar problem... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68574191/javascript-react-highlight-matching-parenthesis/68574437#68574437

Comment: This is very useful! I guess I should be able to solve my problem myself with that. Probably gonna close the question later, thank you! Feel free to drop an answer if you want.

Comment: Plus, the problem and solution themselves are very interesting...

Comment: @a2br Sure, see my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example (might have off-by-one errors or other strangeness).

Live example [here on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fragment-render-mfn30) (can't be bothered to make it a snippet that'd work here because TypeScript, etc.).

```
import React from "react";

interface FragmentedString {
  str: string;
  fragments: Array<{
    id: string;
    start: number;
    end: number;
  }>;
}

function FragmentedStringRenderer({
  fragmentedString,
  renderFragment
}: {
  fragmentedString: FragmentedString;
  renderFragment: (id: string, content: string) => React.ReactChild;
}) {
  const { str, fragments } = fragmentedString;
  const out: React.ReactChild[] = [];
  // Assumes `fragments` is in order and doesn't overlap
  let currStart = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
    const { id, start, end } = fragments[i];
    if (currStart < start) {
      // need to add a plaintext fragment
      out.push(<>{str.substring(currStart, start)}</>);
    }
    out.push(renderFragment(id, str.substring(start, end)));
    currStart = end;
  }
  if (currStart < str.length) {
    // need to add a final fragment
    out.push(<>{str.substring(currStart)}</>);
  }
  return React.createElement(React.Fragment, {}, [...out]);
}

const fs: FragmentedString = {
  str: "Hello, world! Are you happy?",
  fragments: [
    { id: "noun", start: 7, end: 12 },
    { id: "adj", start: 22, end: 27 }
  ]
};


export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FragmentedStringRenderer
        fragmentedString={fs}
        renderFragment={(id: string, text: string) => (
          <a href={`#${id}`}>{text}</a>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```